# Adding UIElements to custom control (WPF)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, uielement

How can I create a custom control which takes a list of `UIElement`s and renders them according to some logic?

Because it will handle a list of `UIElement`s, the best way of adding controls will be the same as for, i.e. `ListBox` or `ComboBox`.

```
<local:SomeControl>
    <Button Content="First"/>
    <Label Content="Something other"/>
</local:SomeControl>
```

Here is the user control's XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="_2009_07_22_Wpf_Smooth_Scroller.SomeControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Some title"/>

        <!-- The inner UIElement to add content to  -->
        <Canvas x:Name="innerPanel" Grid.Row="1"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How can I, for instance, place i-th control to location X = 50 * i, Y = 40 * i ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've described is a WPF `Panel`:

> Use Panel elements to position and
>   arrange child objects in Windows
>   Presentation Foundation (WPF)
>   applications.

That is, you could subclass `Panel` and arrange your children according to your custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a user control to a `Panel`, just use the `Children` property of the panel.
Sample:

```
usercontrolObject = new MyUserControl();
panelobj.Children.Add(usercontrolObject);
```

That's it!